# DotNet DateTime.ToString strange results

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime

Why does:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M")
```

not return the month number? Instead it returns the full month name with the day on it.

Apparently, this is because "M" is also a standard code for the MonthDayPattern. I don't want this...I want to get the month number using "M". Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers), you can use either `"%M"`, `"M "` or `" M"` (**note**: the last two will also include the space in the result) to force M being parsed as the number of month format.

Comment: nice.. but if you have a `Dictionary` with short description key and format value, or you'r take it from database field so `"%MM"` in may will return 55 instead of 05..
Edit: the @Guffa answare to put empty string before `"''M"` - cover it better.

Answer (score 8):

What's happening here is a conflict between standard `DateTime` format strings and custom format specifiers.  The value "M" is ambiguous in that it is both a standard and custom format specifier.  The `DateTime` implementation will choose a standard formatter over a customer formatter in the case of a conflict, hence it is winning here.

The easiest way to remove the ambiguity is to prefix the M with the % char.  This char is way of saying the following should be interpreted as a custom formatter

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("%M");
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for explaining the issue, as well as providing a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use 
`DateTime.Now.Month`?

Comment: maybee for a general solution like dictionary with descriptions and formats

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `System.DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();` to accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 2):

You can put an empty string literal in the format to make it a composite format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("''M")
```

Comment: 10x the best1 (4me =)

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that the % prefix is required for *any* single-character format string when using the `DateTime.ToString(string)` method, even if that string does not represent one of the built-in format string patterns; I came across this issue when attempting to retrieve the current hour. For example, the code snippet:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("h")
```

will throw a `FormatException`. Changing the above to:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("%h")
```

gives the current date's hour.

I can only assume the method is looking at the format string's length and deciding whether it represents a built-in or custom format string.